# Can I call a function in flash projector from windows app?

Tags: flash, externalinterface

Can I call a function in flash projector from windows app?

Like when using ExternalInterface on a browser to comunicate between JS and SWF, only that now I have an windows app and a Flash projector (.exe file).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got a [RemoteObject](http://gertonscorner.wordpress.com/2008/09/06/remoteobject-using-amfphp-and-actionscript-3/) for that.